# How to decrypt and convert to base64 secret value save in AWS KMS via terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-kms

Hello I am very new to AWS and currently exploring KMS.  Now I have a code that can push to KMS as follows:

```
        provider "aws"{
            region = "us-east-1"
            access_key = "..............."
            secret_key = "..............."
        }

        variable "region" {
          type = string
          default = "us-east-1"
        }

        data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {
          state = "available"
        }

        resource "aws_kms_key" "cipher"{
          description = "Ciphertext"
          key_usage = "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT"
          customer_master_key_spec = "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT"
          enable_key_rotation = true
        }

        resource "aws_kms_alias" "cipher"{
          name = "alias/cipherkey"
          target_key_id = aws_kms_key.cipher.key_id
        }

        resource "aws_kms_ciphertext" "services"{
          key_id = aws_kms_key.cipher.key_id
         
          plaintext = <<EOF
          {
            "Jason" : "Password",
            "Ralph" : "Password"
          }
          EOF
        }

        data "aws_kms_secrets" "services"{
          secret {
            name = "services_password"
            payload = aws_kms_ciphertext.services.ciphertext_blob
          }
        }
```

I want it to get back the values saved in my KMS, that plaintext values as shown below.  How to do that via Terraform?

```
            "Jason" : "Password",
            "Ralph" : "Password"
```

Comment: Are there any errors? What have you tried already?

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the current code.  I just need to add a code that will gets the encrypted value then decrypt it then convert it to base64 via terraform. Is that possible?